# Iptables DDos Protection

Tags: command-line, server, iptables

How can I limit connections to this port "27015" for the two protocols TCP/UDP? I need to block some floods that uses this port to send much package per second and take my software running on this port down.

Can you give me some 'iptables" commands that I can use for this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27015 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27015 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 -j REJECT
```

Connlimit:

> Allows you to restrict the number of parallel connections to a server per client IP address (or client address block).

- `--connlimit-above` allow 2 connections per client host