# Script that will scan for number of connections and ban those above 100

Tags: 18.04, scripts, iptables

since I lately have some DDOS attacks, i need help in creating the script that will do following:

-Screen the IPs on all ports with total number of connections using netstat
-Ban all IP's that are having more then 100 connections
-Exclude IP 87.91.143.119 from ban even it has more then 100 connections

would be grateful for advices
thank you

Comment: You should probably look at doing this via the kernel's own packet filtering mechanism rather than rolling your own script - see for example [Iptables DDos Protection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930111/iptables-ddos-protection)

Comment: thanks, how do you apply this rule to all ports, not only 27015?
When I put:
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 100:65535 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT

then I cannot connect to server at all, even 1 single connection.

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 443-m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT

then it works fine, it blocks only connections on that port

Comment: I don't know - sorry. You might want to ask that as a specific question, either here or on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)